# Figure won't compile

Tags: includegraphics

I am trying to add a picture in the same folder, subfolder pictures, named iphone.png, but it will terminate with an error.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \label{fig:iphoneCropped}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[trim=0 5cm 0 5cm, clip]{../pictures/iphone.png}
        \caption{Pictures of site on iphone}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:iphoneCropped}
Also it will refer to this picture as being subsubsection III-A1, instead of as figure.


\end{document}
```

Comment: what error message did you get? Also note that `\label` must be after `\caption`.

Comment: from your description I would expect you want `{pictures/iphone.png}` rather than `{../pictures/iphone.png}` but impossible to say.   (The comment in the last line of your example is due to `\label` being in the wrong pace as noted in the first comment)

Comment: Package pdftex.def Error: File '../pictures/iphone.png' not found: using draft setting. 

Thank you David it now finds the picture, and the right ref type :)!!!
I didn't know the label placing meant so much.

Answer (score 3):

The path needs to be relative to the directory where tex is run, and `\label` needs to be after, or in, `\caption`

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Alt}{alt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
        \includegraphics[trim=0 5cm 0 5cm, clip]{pictures/iphone.png}
        \caption{Pictures of site on iphone\label{fig:iphoneCropped}}

\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:iphoneCropped}
Also it will refer to this picture as being subsubsection III-A1, instead of as figure.


\end{document}
```